# Parsing Address in Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to parse up the addresses in a table using the above code. It runs but only produces `NULL`. I have run out of ideas

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What do your addresses look like?  Can you please [edit] your question to include 3 or 4 example addresses?  Also what are you expecting your output to look like?

Comment: Please also [edit] your question and put your code as text.  This makes it copyable for potential answerers, and searchable for users in the future looking for a solution to similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include a `return` value to pass your new value back to your field.  I don't know what your addresses look like, or the expected output, but here is an example:

Pre-logic code=

```
def myParser(inString):
    splitString = inString.split(' ')
    a = splitString[0]
    c = ''.join(splitString[2:-1])
    d = splitString[-1]

    return "{0} {1} {2}".format(a, c, d)
```

Expression=

```
myParser(!PhysAddr!)
```

---

With a bit of a play with your code, I think your line for `c` should actually be the following:

```
c = ''.join(splitString[1:-1]
```

Although it may be different if you've got different addresses to mine.